# How to send or update data as state or prop to app.jsx from child component

Tags: reactjs, components

I am new in react js.

I need to change the whole view on click of button

For this i need to update parent component's state from child component.

Like we do as a session variable. Do you guys have any idea about it then please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code :

**App.jsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

render() {
    let RedirectTo = this.state.page;
    let RenderPage;

    switch (RedirectTo) {
        case 'component':
            RenderPage = true && <NextPage />;
            break;
        default:
            RenderPage = true && <Index />;
    }

    return (
            <div>
                {RenderPage}
            </div>
            );
}
```

**Child.jsx**

```
class Child extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {redirect: 'yes'};
    this.state = {page: 'component'};
}

render() {
    if (this.state.redirect === 'yes') {
        return (
                <div>
                    { true && <App /> }
                </div>
                );
    } else {
        return (
                <div>
                    <a onClick={this.Validate} href="javascript:void(0);">
                        Click To Next
                    </a>  
                </div>
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this everywhere: `RenderPage = true && <NextPage />;`?

Comment: @JanHančič as i mentioned i am in learning stage. I did not about that. is it wrong? then please suggest me the solution. so i can proceed further. Thanks

Comment: You don't need that. Just use `RenderPage = <NextPage />;` directly for example.

Comment: But with this code i can only render the layout and i need to change the whole view of page with prop change. Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Sorry, from the code you posted it seems you're lacking the basic understanding of how JS and React work, so it's hard to give a good answer. I would suggest you go back to learning the basics of JavaScript and then read the beginner tutorials on React.

Comment: oops ! That is fine. May be my way is wrong of putting question. Let me rephrase my question. Do you have any good reference code how can we update parent component's state from child component ?

Comment: The parent needs to pass a function, as a prop, to the child. The child then invokes the function which actually modifies the state of the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, React component working on Parent to child manner not child to parent, whatever function you want to call which can affect your parent from child  then you have to pass the props into child and invocation happen through the parent so that will affect your parent as well as child,

What you want to tried to achieve is wrong way you have to introduce the Router in your application which can route the one page to another one you need to check the React-Router for that so basically navigation of one component to another component we can easily achieve using react-router, [React-Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function in parent like

```
function () {
// your functionality here
}
```

then call the child component in parent as

```
<child functionProp = {this.function} />
```

In your child component call the function in parent by

```
this.props.functionProp
```

Comment: i need to update parent's state from child component. You wrote code for parent to child.

Comment: Whatever you do in child will call that function in parent as well
i just told you the way you can try only
This is how parent and child are connected
Maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

In parent you can pass a function as `props` to the child as:

```
<child someFunction={this.handleFunction} />
```

And in `handleFunction` method in parent you can do whatever you want.

```
handleFunction(value) {
    //do something
}
```

And in child you can call that `someFunction` as:

```
this.props.someFunction(value)
```

In this way you can communicate to parent through child.